# Call js function from code-behind (Not as startupScript)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Basically what I want to do is:

1. Click on a button to delete a record.
2. Delete the record if a specific column (Location) is null (this is done and works fine)
3. Delete the record, BUT if the specific column is not null, ask the user to confirm.

So step 3 is the tricky part. With the AJAX, I call the `deleteChannel(url)` that you see below, which calls the proper method in code-behind. Now here is the tricky part:

```
   if (channel != null && channel.Location != null)
    {
         // How do I do this? (Notice that this is code-behind)
         ShowDialogThatAsksUserToConfirm()
    }
```

The code: `ShowDialogThatAsksUserToConfirm()` needs to call back to the client saying that "The Location column is not null", and wait for user to say delete anyway, or cancel.

I have this code that will call a method in code behind:

```
function deleteChannel(url) {

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (msg) {
        showDialog('successDiv');
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
        showDialog('errorDiv');
    }
});
}
```

And the showDialog(...) looks like this:

```
function showDialog(divID) {
$("#" + divID).dialog({
    show: "clip",
    hide: "clip",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
}
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteChannel(int id)
    {
        var statusCode = new HttpStatusCode();

        using (var context = new MaaneGrisContext())
        {
            var channel = context.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

            if (channel != null && channel.Location != null)
            {
                if (Confirmation()) //The Confirmation() method not implemented yet, but it should ask user to confirm
                {
                    context.Channels.Remove(channel);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    List<ChannelModel> updatedChannelList = new List<ChannelModel>();
                    context.Channels.AddRange(context.Channels);



                    return View("ChannelDetails", updatedChannelList);
                }
            }
  }
```

Here is the View:

```
<table style="border: ridge 1px">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        ...
    </tr>
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ChannelName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Unit)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Location.StableName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreationDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.LastEdited)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ExtraNote)</td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("CopyChannel", "Channel", new { id = item.ID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span></a></td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("EditChannel", "Channel", new { id = item.ID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteChannel('@Url.Action("DeleteChannel", "Channel", new { id = item.ID })')">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }        
</table>
<br/><br/>
<div style="display: none;">
   @* @{ Html.RenderPartial("_CreateChannel"); } *@
</div>
<h5>@Html.ActionLink("Opret en ny kanal", "RegisterChannel", "Channel")</h5>

<div id="cautionDiv" title="Bekræft sletning" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: red;">The channel has a location. Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
</div>

<div id="successDiv" title="Info" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: green;">Deleted</p>
</div>
```

This is just my approach, and is not final, if there are better solutions, please let me know

Comment: What about splitting your "webapi" method into two distinct methods - one that checks whether it is possible or not to do the processing and returns some flag to the client and second that can unquestionably commit the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call js from a codebehind, but your ajax method can return an indication for asking the user:

```
if (channel != null && channel.Location != null)
{
   return 'cannot-delete';
}
```

and the ajax method would see that on it's success function, and prompt the user:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == 'cannot-delete') {
             ShowDialogThatAsksUserToConfirm();
        } else showDialog('successDiv');
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
        showDialog('errorDiv');
    }
});
```

The method `ShowDialogThatAsksUserToConfirm` should ask for the users's confirmation in javascript, and if allowed, submit a forced delete of the record.